# Reading then writing to the same excel file works in IDE, not in JAR

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

When I run this code in NetBeans IDE 8.2 it updates the excel file without incident.  However when I build the JAR I get the following error when I run this part of the code "java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\D:\Projects\ht\ht\dist\ht.jar!\HTAlarms_1.xlsx".  It reads the excel file just fine, however I am doing something wrong when I am trying to write to the excel file.

```
public void setAlarmFileContents() {
    System.out.println("Inside of setAlarmFileContents");
    String fileName = "HTAlarms_1.xlsx";
    ClassLoader classLoader = new ht().getClass().getClassLoader();
    InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);

    try {
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(is);
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        Row row = sheet.getRow(123);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(2);
        cell.setCellValue("Testing Data Worked inside of IDE");

        is.close();
        System.out.println("Input stream is closed");


        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        workbook.close();
        outputStream.close();
        System.out.println("Streams closed data set?");


    } catch (IOException | EncryptedDocumentException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: you want your active jar file to change your active jar file? you understand that since it's in use, you can't just update it?

Comment: I would like the user to be able to update the excel file that is inside of the jar file from within the application by typing the updated text and the pressing a jButton to update the contents.

Comment: yes, but you do understand that the jar is actually running at that point?

Comment: So a better approach would be to store the file to be read and written to externally, say on a network share?  Sorry, this is my first go round with java.

Comment: Pointed to a network share and it worked as I intended it to.  Thank you for your time.